# Problems with moving site to new host

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have moved my php site to a new host but this is causing massive problems, namely with the require(mysqli_connect.php) which, ofcourse is to connect to the database. Any file that has this require does not load up, leaving just a blank page. These pages worked perfectly fine before switching and work fine if I comment out the require. Would the db not connecting cause this require to fail?

I haven't used php for 2 years+ now, so sorry if this is not enough detail, but not sure what more I can give.

Comment: Check apache error log (Typically in /var/logs/apache/error_log or something like that) and/or set PHP's setting error_reporting to E_ALL and display_errors to 1. This will tell you the error that is happening. Include the error you get in your question.

Comment: Check that the path to mysqli_connect.php file is correct in this new host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqli might not be installed on that server. Either ask the admin of the server to solve this problem, or if it is yours, check this out:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.setup.php

Comment: A quick phpinfo() should reveal if this is the case.

Comment: I have to wait for the admin to come back online but I will check this

Comment: Thanks captain giraffe, I tried that and not sure what to do with that information, I see no mysqli section just mssql and mysql

Comment: @babyrats Then your only options are -get the admin to install it or -switch to mysql.

Comment: If I remember right the mysql has different parameters? if that is the case this will be a major pain in the ***

Comment: It would not be easy to rewrite it all. The admin should be able to install mysqli quite easily though.

Comment: Okay I will try to beg him to do that, thanks for the help guys

Comment: Well... isn't that his bloody job? :)

Answer (score 0):

Enable PHP error reporting to see what the error really is. In the script itself, before the `require('mysqli_connect.php')`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

or in `.htaccess` file

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting E_ALL
```